# Linux - Duplicate a virtual memory address from malloc or move a virtual memory address

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, malloc

**Short question:**
Is it possible to map a buffer that has been malloc'd to have two ways (two pointers pointing to the same physical memory) of accessing the same buffer?
Or, is it possible to temporarily move a virtual memory address received by malloc? Or is it possible to point from one location in virtual space to another?

**Background:**
I am working with `DirectFB`, a surface management and 2D graphics composting library. I am trying to enforce the Locking protocol which is to Lock a surface, modify the memory only while locked (the pointer is to system memory allocated using malloc), and unlocking the surface.

I am currently trying to trace down a bug in an application that is locking a surface and then storing the pixel pointer and modifying the surface later. This means that the library does not know when it is safe to read or write to a surface. I am trying to find a way to detect that the locking protocol has been violated. What I would like is a way to invalidate the pointer passed to the user after the unlock call is made. Even better, I would like the application to seg fault if it tries to access the memory after the lock. This would stop in the debugger and give us an idea of which surface is involved, which routine is involved, who called it, etc.

**Possible solutions:**

> 1. Create a temporary buffer, pass the buffer pointer to the user, on unlock copy the pixels to the actual buffer, delete the temporary
>      buffer.
>
>    - Pros: This is an implementable solution.
>    - Cons: Performance is slow as it requires a copy which is expensive, also the memory may or may not be available. There is no
>        way to guarantee that one temporary surface overlaps another allowing
>        an invalidated pointer to suddenly work again.
> 2. Make an additional map to a malloc'd surface and pass that to the user. On unlock, unmap the memory.
>
>    - Pros: Very fast, no additional memory required.
>    - Cons: Unknown if this is possible.
>    - Gotchas: Need to set aside a reserved range of addresses are never used by anything else (including malloc or the kernel). Also need to
>        ensure that no two surfaces overlap which could allow an old pointer
>        to suddenly point to something valid and not seg fault when it should.
> 3. Take advantage of the fact that the library does not access the memory while locked by the user and simply move the virtual address on
>      a lock and move it back on an unlock.
>
>    - Pros: Very fast, no additional memory required.
>    - Cons: Unknown if this is possible.
>    - Gotchas: Same as "2" above.

Is this feasible?

**Additional info:**

> - This is using `Linux 2.6`, using *stdlib*.
> - The library is written in `C`.
> - The library and application run in user space.
> - There is a possibility of using a kernel module (to write a custom memory allocation routine), but the difficulty of writing a module in
>     my current working climate would probably reduce the chances to near
>     zero levels that I could actually implement this solution. But if this
>     is the only way, it would be good to know.
> - The underlying processor is `x86`.

Comment: Do you want a copy of the memory range or do you just want a second pointer to it?

Comment: I would like a second pointer to it that can then be invalidated upon the Unlock call.

Comment: This has to be possible... I think it's commonly done for things like circular buffers (where the buffer is mapped twice, sequentially, in memory, so any up-to-full-buffer sized read/write can just be a single `memcpy`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you want to create multiple mappings of a page is `shm_open`.

You may only be using the memory within one process, but it's still "shared memory" - that is to say, multiple virtual mappings for the same underlying physical page will exist.

However, that's not what you want to **do**. What you should actually do is have your locking functions use the `mprotect` system call to render the memory unreadable on unlock and restore the permissions on lock; any access without the lock being held will cause a segfault. Of course, this'll only work with a single simultaneous accessing thread...

Another, possibly better, way to track down the problem would be to run your application in `valgrind` or another memory analysis tool. This will greatly slow it down, but allows you very fine control: you can have a valgrind script that will mark/unmark memory as accessible and the tool will kick you straight into the debugger when a violation occurs. But for one-off problem solving like this, I'd say install an `#ifdef DEBUG`-wrapped `mprotect` call in your lock/unlock functions.

Comment: I didn't know about mprotect. Thanks for the recommendation. The only problem with mprotect would be that the library still needs access to the memory. The library of course does have an internal locking mechanism that could also use mprotect (which would be more protection than what is currently done), however there would still be a window of opportunity for the application to sneak in while the library has the surface locked. I will have to consider your valgrind idea, but I am concerned it may have a similar window of opportunity.

Comment: @user1539433 You could register a fault handler which examines the current stack trace and, if it leads to the library's own internal accessor methods, discards the SEGV. This would work with `mprotect` or a valgrind script.